# Non-lvalues as function parameters in C++

Tags: c++

I'm reading Accelerated C++ and in Chapter 4 they bring up the concept of lvalues. There's an example of something that *shouldn't* work, but after trying it myself I found that it does indeed work.

Specifically they state that, given these functions:

```
// return an empty vector
vector<double> emptyvec()
{
  vector<double> v;
  return v;
}

// read things from an input stream into a vector<double>
// (I'm leaving out the function body here because it's irrelevant)
istream &read_things(istream& in, vector<double>& hw);
```

This should not be allowed:

```
read_stuff( cin, emptyvec() );
```

Because emptyvec() is an expression and returns a temporary object (a *non-lvalue* as they called it in the book). However, this not only compiles but actually runs (Windows 7/VisualStudio 2010).

So, what's going on? Was this just a bad example on the authors' part, or is there something else happening that I don't understand.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you double check the return type of `emptyvec()`?  As given (`vector<double> vector`) it doesn't make much sense.  Was this `vector<double> &` in the book (in which case the code is indeed an example of the problem the book mentions)?

Comment: @jimwise That was a typo when I entered it here. The original program was actually written correctly :)

Comment: Which way?  Returning `vector<double>` or `vector<double> &`?

Comment: @jimwise (The original typo was `vector<double> vector emptyvec()` which is not valid syntax)

I don't have the book here at the moment, but when I tried changing it from `vector<double>` to `vector<double>&` the compiler threw an error: warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary

So that seems to be more in line with what the author was saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concern the book mentions would come into play if the function was declared as:

```
vector<double> &emptyvec()
```

or

```
vector<double> *emptyvec()
```

as it would then be returning a temporary value *by reference*, and by the time you used the reference, the value it referred to would be gone.  Your compiler should issue a warning or an error for this case, and you might (but might not) see a variety of possible failures at run time (sadly, the type of error you would see could vary widely).

On the other hand, if the function is indeed declared as

```
vector<double> emptyvec()
```

the vector is being returned *by value* (i.e. a copy of the actual vector is being made into wherever you store the return value), and the program should work correctly.

Comment: Ah yes, I just realized this after reading your earlier comment. So this was probably all down to me misreading the example in the book.

The compiler throws an error now and I even get a runtime exception (access violation reading a memory location) and everything makes total sense now.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad I could help!  :-)

Comment: @Alex: Was it a typo in the book? Maybe it's worth contacting the author.

Answer (score 0):

It's a compiler extension on the part of Visual Studio. The code should indeed not compile, and it won't on the other major compilers like GCC and Clang, as a temporary cannot bind to a mutable reference.

Comment: The `vector` is passed by value, which is perfectly fine.

Comment: Why the downvotes? He's right. This _shouldn't_ compile according to the C++ standard. There's no problem in `emptyvec()`, it's in `read_things()` binding a temporary (the return value of `emptyvec()`) to a non-const reference parameter.

Comment: It's certainly not perfectly fine when it tries to give a *value* `vector` to a mutable reference parameter.